# Resolve URL to 0.0.0.0/127.0.0.1/localhost

Tags: dns

I'd like to use a real URL instead of `localhost` for local development (so I can make my development environment more similar to production, not have to remember which port is associated with which service, and have valid certs).

I added an A record to my DNS records for my domain (`*.myname.example.com -> 0.0.0.0`), but I'm getting a "refused to connect" error; do I need to change something on my machine (e.g. I tried adding the same mapping to `/etc/hosts`)? I similarly tried an A record to `127.0.0.1` and a CNAME to `penguin.linux.test` (this resolves to `0.0.0.0` on my host, see below for my setup which has this `/etc/hosts` rule by default).

For more context (i.e. why editing `/etc/hosts` is insufficient), I can't actually edit `/etc/hosts` on my machine, only on the VM my code is running in. More specifically, my stack is below.

- ChromeOS host
- Crostini Arch linux container
- Traefik docker container that routes subdomains to the appropriate services

To resolve any ambiguity about the root of the problem being more fundamental, this works perfectly well if I set my DNS rules to an A record that points to my external IP address (when I'm on a network that allows port forwarding, which isn't always the case, another reason I'm trying to use `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`/`0.0.0.0`).

Comment: A perfect answer exists on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229126/using-domain-name-instead-of-localhost-in-with-https-in-xampp/38348820

Comment: @Kinnectus Thank you for that suggestion, but unfortunately I already saw that and several other similar answers and they are not relevant to my purposes. See my edited post for clarification about why that is the case.

Comment: If you're running VMs then you could probably run a DNS server in a new VM that you configure your dev domains to your docker and other platform IPs and then configure your OS to use your new DNS to resolve your dev domains before going out to your default gateway

Comment: Hi, can you confirm that: 1 - you did change the A record to 127.0.0.1 as @farhan-k said; 2 - you can resolve with nslookup or ping the host.myname.example.com as 127.0.0.1; and 3 - when you use localhost it effectively works. Thanks

Comment: My setup is nonstandard: I'm trying to access a container from the host, the container's IP is dynamic, and I can't manually edit `/etc/hosts`. The host's `/etc/hosts` file, however, is dynamically updated to reflect the container's IP address (at `penguin.linux.test`). I have confirmed that if I manually add an A record in cloudflare `*.myname.example.com` -> `100.xxx.xxx.xxx` (container's local IP) it all works. However, if I replace that A record with a CNAME `*.myname.example.com` -> `penguin.linux.test` it fails (`** server can't find test.myname.example.com: NXDOMAIN` from `nslookup`).

Answer (score 4):

You’re probably mistaking `0.0.0.0` with `127.0.0.1`.

[`127.0.0.1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#Name_resolution) is a loopback address which `localhost` usually resolves to (this is set by default in the hosts file). `0.0.0.0` is a non-routable meta address.

Comment: See my edit for some clarifications, but I tried that as well without success. Thanks for the info though, I never really understood the difference (and I'm still a bit fuzzy on it tbh, but have some more context at least).

Comment: @Californian Sorry I might not be understanding the question properly. Can you have a look at Jorge Valentini's comment and provide some of that information. It might help to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some admin, make their web application resolve to localhost `127.0.0.1` and your computer when making the request could store the information

Example:  www.example.com can have the web Admin

```
     app.example.com 127.0.0.1 in the A record
```

And your machine would also store the above. Only that the localhost is now your machine rather than `app.example.com`